# How can I get Monitor Connection information from Wayland?

Tags: linux, wayland

When running under X, I can get information about the monitor connection as follows:

```
$ xrandr --verbose

DP-0.8 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (0x1bd) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
    ...
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 3 
    _ConnectorLocation: 3 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  2560x1440 (0x1bd) 241.500MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
  ...
```

This information is available to applications via `XRRListOutputProperties` in `#include <X11/extensions/Xrandr.h>`

Is there an equivalent when running under Wayland? Specifically I need the information provided by `ConnectorType` and `ConnectorNumber`

Comment: Wayland by itself is just a set of specs describing a communication protocol. So the specific command really depends on the compositor (implementor) at hand. For sway, for example, it's `swaymsg -t output`. So the question should include what compositor you are using.

Comment: I use wlr-randr but I do not think it gives you ConnectorType and ConnectorNumber :(